# Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: reactjs, api

I have a login form (Username and Password) written in a React JS environment; the form consumes a REST API that contains the user credentials. I'm using the Fetch method to consume the API, but it errors out. I need to access the service via POST, but when I check (via chrome console - Network tab ) how my application is accessing the service, it states that the request method used is GET. How do I modify my code to access the form using post? Here is my code snippet I'm using to consume the web APT:

```
class Login extends Component {

    //constructor
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state={
         data: [],
        }
    } 

    //componet did mount method
    componentDidMount(){
        return fetch('http://myjson.com/file')
        .then((response)=>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>
        {

           this.setState({
               data:responseJson.token
           })
           console.log(this.state.data)
        })
   }
```

I researched using the request.method but I'm uncertain how to implement it into the code. Could I get some help with this please? ...thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fetch('http://myjson.com/users/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: 'userName',
    password: 'pwd',
  })
})
```

Here is fetch [docs](https://github.com/github/fetch)

## Edit

```
componentDidMount(){

    return fetch('http://myjson.com/users/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        username: 'userName',
        password: 'pwd',
      })
    })
    .then((response)=>response.json())
    .then((responseJson)=>
    {

       this.setState({
           data:responseJson.token
       })
       console.log(this.state.data)
    })
}
```

Comment: Artem Mirchenko - thanks, but is there a way to make the post request using the script I provided? The snippet I provided successfully consumed one Rest API, I assume it required GET and it displayed the results of the API in my page (I was following a tutorial on consuming API's using fetch), but for this other API, I need it to use POST; so I tested the script you provided on the page I created via the tutorial and the results of the API no longer displayed. Do I need to use both snippets (mine and yours) or can I consume and access the API using  the code you provided only?

Comment: Yea you can combine mine and your code to get valid result for you, i edit my answer, look at there example.